# Flutter Bottom navigationbar pops up on top of the keypad when on tapped form text field while running in iPhone device

Tags: flutter, navigation

when i try to enter text which is inside form field. Bottomnavigationbar shows up just above the keypad. How do i fix the Bottomnavigationbar / hide it so that it doesn't show up on keypad?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property of the `Scaffold` to `false` ?

Comment: yes tried it . Still works the same.is there any other way to solve this ? @SiddharthPatankar